# the 'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine while reading a excel file in c#

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, oledbconnection

I am reading an excel file and I want to access its contents.
I am using this connection string:

```
connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", Server.MapPath(fileName));
```

But I see this error:

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine.

My server is running on 64-bit operating system.
I have installed Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010(32-bit) and Microsoft Access database engine 2010 on it.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the following links, if they solve the issue that you are encountering:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/280/solved-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-mac

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/417397/OLEDB-Provider-is-Not-Registered-on-the-Local-Mach

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f11b2df9-fd0a-4528-987f-f95dfdccee0a/microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-error?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Last one suggests downloading a patch from - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Your first link solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the ACE.OLEDB.12.0 dosen't work in the 64-bit Operating system.

You can refer this [forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f11b2df9-fd0a-4528-987f-f95dfdccee0a/microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-error?forum=adodotnetdataproviders) as well. You have to [download the patch from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).